# high level function that gets rid of overlapping x,y coordinates

Tags: python

The screen shot pretty much says it all. I'm trying to find a function that, given 2 sets of x,y coordinates, in this case the first set would be the circle and the second set would be the blue figure, keep the second set of xy coordinates that are outside of the first set of x,y coordinates
[image: example pic]

Comment: If one of the shapes is known as a circle, square, or rectangle you can do it easily. For ex. for a circle by calculating the distance from the center, if it is greater than the radius you keep it, if not you discard it.

Comment: The [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library might come in handy if you need to handle the trickier cases, like clipping non-convex polygons with holes in them.